# Catch exception from parallel stream

Tags: java, exception, parallel-processing, java-8, java-stream

I have a bunch of columns as string arrays from a csv file. Now I want to parse them. Since this parsing requires date parsing and other not so fast parsing techniques I was thinking about parallelism (I timed it, it takes some time). My simple approach:

```
Stream.of(columns).parallel().forEach(column -> 
    result[column.index] = parseColumn(valueCache[column.index], column.type));
```

Columns contains `ColumnDescriptor` elements which simply has two attributes, the column index to be parsed and the type which defines how to parse it. Nothing else. result is an Object array which takes the resulting arrays.

The problem is now that the parse function throws a ParseException, that I handle further up the call stack. Since we are in parallel here it can't just be thrown. What is the best way to handle this?

I have this solution, but I kind of cringe reading it. What would be a better way to do it?

```
final CompletableFuture<ParseException> thrownException = new CompletableFuture<>();
Stream.of(columns).parallel().forEach(column -> {
    try {
        result[column.index] = parseColumn(valueCache[column.index], column.type);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        thrownException.complete(e);
    }});

if(thrownException.isDone())
    //only can be done if there is a value set.
    throw thrownException.getNow(null);
```

Notes: I do not need all the exceptions. If I parse them sequentially I will also only get one anyway. So that is ok.

Comment: For me it is readable other possibility I can think of suppressed exceptions so you can also store column numbers but stack trace will be huge , addsuppressed method synchronised as well or simply build a user friendly message

Comment: I guess this is more of an experiment, because it's unlikely that parsing will be taking up a significant amount of time vs. reading from CSV file (ie, this is premature optimization).  If you parsed while reading the file, you would probably find that everything is parsed at the same time the reading finishes.

Comment: The reading the data is a one time operation. But the parsing wil be done repeatedly with different settings. That's why I want to optimize that part.

Comment: Why does your “simple approach” not work? You didn’t explain that, besides claiming that you can’t do it.

Answer (score 9):

The problem is your wrong premise “Since we are in parallel here it can't just be thrown.” There is no specification forbidding throwing exceptions in parallel processing. You can just throw that exception in a parallel stream the same way you do in a sequential stream, wrapping it in an unchecked exception, if it is a checked exception.

If there is at least one exception thrown in a thread, the `forEach` invocation will propagate it (or one of them) to the caller.

The only issue you might encounter, is, that the current implementation doesn’t wait for the completion of all threads when it encounters an exception. This can be worked around using

```
try {
    Arrays.stream(columns).parallel()
        .forEach(column -> 
            result[column.index] = parseColumn(valueCache[column.index], column.type));
} catch(Throwable t) {
    ForkJoinPool.commonPool().awaitQuiescence(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
    throw t;
}
```

But usually, you don’t need it as you won’t access the concurrently processed result in the exceptional case.

Comment: First thanks for taking the time for that answer. That would lead to the same point as in john16384 answer. I don't like to throw an exception in a multi thread environment. Exception bubbeling over multiple threads is something that I learned as a no go when I learned to work with Threads. So even though it works, I am not quite satisfied.

Comment: @findusl: it would be interesting, who has told you that with what rationale, as avoiding something the rest of your lifetime, just because someone said something bad about it some day, sounds quite dogmatic. And your attempt to avoid it doesn’t even change something, neither semantically nor technically. `parseColumn` is still throwing an exception in a multi-threaded execution and someone will catch it and hand it over to the job initiating thread. Why should it be better when you do it manually, instead of letting the Stream framework do it?

Comment: The one problem I can see is that the stream breaks a checked exception bubble flow, which from that perspective can be a bit of a nuisance.

Comment: @FrankHopkins but that’s not different from a sequential stream.

Comment: @Holger true, not arguing against your answer at all. It's just the one thing I could see that led to the establishment of such a "rule" or that in general could lead people to try and avoid the combination of those two concepts. Though, as you say, it's more to do with streams than with parallelisation.

Answer (score 2):

I think the question is more, what do you normally do when parsing it serially?

Do you stop at the first exception, and stop the entire process?  In that case, wrap the exception in a run time exception, and let the stream abort and throw it.  Catch the wrapper exception, unwrap it and deal with it.

Do you skip the bad records?  Then either 1. keep track of the errors in a List somewhere or 2. create a wrapper object that can hold either a parsed result or an error (don't track the exceptions themselves, only the minimum needed to describe the error).

Check afterwards if there were errors in the list for the first option, or display the records that had errors differently for the second option.

Comment: The runtime exception does work. I like it more than my solution. Still don't like it so much, because I throw a RuntimeException through parallel threads like this. Something I learned to avoid when programming parallel. But since stream handles it for me, I guess if I don't get a better answer these days soon I'll mark yours correct :)