# Execute parallel method calls in java without aborting entire processing for any exception in a one or multiple method calls

Tags: java, spring-boot, parallel-processing, java-stream, java-threads

I've a method

```
private void disableXYZ(Long rId, List<Long> disableIds, String requestedBy) {
        for (Long disableId : disableIds) {
            try {
                disablePackXYZ(UnSubscribeRequest.unsubscriptionRequest()
                        .requestedBy(requestedBy)
                        .cancellationReason("system")
                        .id(disableId)
                        .build());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error("Failed to disable pack. id: {}, rId: {}. Error: {}", disableId, rId, e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    }
```

I want to make parallel method calls to disablePackXYZ with ids in disableIds list instead of an iterative for loop. But doing so I don't want to abort all the parallel calls if exception is thrown by any one or more disablePackXYZ calls. I can catch or suppress the exception but it should not abort processing of all the other threads or of the same thread for further tasks. Please suggest the approach for the same.

I went through java streams approach over the web -

```
final CompletableFuture<ParseException> thrownException = new CompletableFuture<>();
Stream.of(columns).parallel().forEach(column -> {
    try {
        result[column.index] = parseColumn(valueCache[column.index], column.type);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        thrownException.complete(e);
    }});
```

For above approach, I found over web that if there is at least one exception thrown in a thread, the forEach invocation will propagate it (or one of them) to the caller. Hence, the current implementation doesn’t wait for the completion of all threads when it encounters an exception.

Comment: You could simply catch exceptions in the loop. If you catch them, are you thinking execution would stop?

Comment: Thanks for the reply Chris. I was actually doubtful on this. Pl refer to the top upvoted answer on - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032904/catch-exception-from-parallel-stream . Please let me know your views on this.

Comment: A quote from that: _If there is at least one exception **thrown** in a thread_. If you catch an exception it doesn't have to be re-thrown. You can still catch it and continue execution with the rest of the stream.

Comment: Hey Chris, we know that multiple threads will be spun by Stream.of(columns).parallel() provided the collection is very large. In my usecase, I need to revert the changes made by a thread if exception occurs in any of the threads spun up kind of Transactional rollback. 

I'm using parallel streams to make api more performant as for each processing it has db and service to service calls. Can this be achieved by parallel streams or maybe can you please suggest an efficient approach for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a result[] array for storing results, just create an error[] array for storing exceptions. In your catch statement, store the exception into the error[] array and don't call thrownException.complete(e).

Comment: Thanks for the reply Jesse. But does that guarantee, if an exception is thrown during processing task in any one of the forEach iteration won't abort remaining threads(forEach iterations)? Pl refer to the top upvoted answer on - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43032904/catch-exception-from-parallel-stream and let me know your views on this.

Comment: Yes, it does, because you would be catching the exception and not throwing it within the loop.

Comment: Hey Jesse, we know that multiple threads will be spun by Stream.of(columns).parallel() provided the collection is very large. In my usecase, I need to revert the changes made by a thread if exception occurs in any of the threads spun up kind of Transactional rollback. I'm using parallel streams to make api more performant as for each processing it has db and service to service calls. Can this be achieved by parallel streams or maybe can you please suggest an efficient approach for this?

Comment: Just iterate through the error[] array after you finish processing; any non-null value in the array means that at least one thread had an error. If that happens, rollback your transaction.